# Problems with server services on Raspberry Pi3

Tags: raspbian, ssh, php, mysql

I have a Raspberry Pi 3 with Raspbian installed on it. However, I've tried also tried Ubuntu Mate, and I had the same problem. After a while my LAMP server, SSH server and FTP server become unreachable. I tried to see if it was a problem with the connection, but the ICMP protocol worked perfectly. Does anyone have any advice?

EDIT: this morning worked well for about an hour before the problem.

Comment: Have you tried looking into the logs for these things?

Comment: The service status says that the service is running, it's just unreachable from other hosts

Comment: You should edit in exactly what error you get:  Does it time out or does the application give you a message right away that it is *unreachable*?  Or is it saying it cannot find the host by name?

Comment: The problem is that i don't get any errors in the server. I just got a "Connection Refused" from any client i try to use.

Comment: You should check locally to confirm the ports are open, e.g., `lsof -i tcp:80` for a normal HTTP server should show apache/httpd there.  If not the server has gone down.  If it is there something strange is perhaps going on with DNS.  Clarify the context by explaining where the server is in relation to the clients: Are they all on a home LAN?  If so, how does the server get an IP and how is the hostname resolution taking place? Avahi?

Comment: So, nmap show that all ports are correct, it's a Lan server and the ip is static so there's no problem about this.

Comment: My next step would be to run [wireshark](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wireshark) on one of the clients to see what is actually happening.  That is definitive.  Since you are not getting a timeout, *something* is sending you a icmp packet saying there's nothing to connect to (i.e., port is open but unused) or that it is blocked by a firewall.  You need to get the IP address of that something.  It seems very unlikely to be a firewall on the pi if it only happens after an arbitrary amount of time.  Unfortunately wireshark may take some getting used to, but it is also very very useful.

Comment: You're going to need to learn how to filter the wireshark output; `tcp.port==80` may be a useful start (there's a box in the GUI for that).

Answer (score 0):

Sounds to me like the network adapter is timing out. This is a problem that caused me months of hassles on my RPi2; however it was all solved when I made a small entry in one of the network files. Problem: I cannot remmeber what it was that I changed and I cannot find the post that gave me the solution.
But hopefully some other RPiman will use this as a clue to help you.

Cheers, ianm